# Using javascript dates and posting to nancy

Tags: javascript, post, nancy

I'm trying to post a date from a post form to nancy, decoded using model binding. I seem unable to do this. How does this work? I've tried using unixtimestamps and also a string in as the time value `new Date().toLocaleString()` but nancy is unable to decode, complaining that the datetime is in an unsupported format for the latter.

How can i send a date from a form - populated by javascript - for it to be accepted by Nancy's modelbinding?

Comment: Who is this nancy?

Comment: Find documentation or an example where date is used with Nancy and look up its format. Then you will have one less variable in the equation.

Comment: You should try [`toISOString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString). The default Json date format is ISO compliant, I suppose the same is for other content-types.

Answer (score 0):

Nancy's [default `DateTimeConverter`](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy/ModelBinding/DefaultConverters/DateTimeConverter.cs) (which is invoked when binding from Query string or Form) simply uses `System.Convert.ChangeType` for converting `string` to `DateTime`.

Your safest choice is to use an ISO 8601 compliant date/time format, which will be parsed independently from the request culture.

Try converting your date using JavaScript's [`toISOString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) method before sending values to your Nancy module.